# How to create a custom thread pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I'm using C# with .NET Framework 4.5.  I'm writing a server application that should be able to connect to arbitrarily many clients at once.  So I have one thread that will listen for connections, and then it will send the connection to a background thread to go into a loop waiting for messages.  Since the number of supportable client connections should be very high, spawning a new thread for every connection won't work.  Instead what I need is a thread pool.  However, I don't want to use the system thread pool because these threads will essentially be blocked in a call to `Socket.Select` indefinitely, or at least for the life of the connections they host.

So I think I need a custom ThreadPool that I can explicitly round-robin the connections over to.  How to achieve this in C#?

Comment: Bit of an XY Problem here. You have a requirement and have prescribed a solution and are asking about that particular solution and not the problem itself. You are correct in not wanting threads associated with a single connection that does nothing. Threads are not lightweight objects. The concept is similar to Stackless Python tasklets with a scheduler. I think the new TPL stuff can achieve this idea, it has the concept of a thread pool and a "blocking IO" thread pool, it might be worth investigating that, perhaps using TPL DataFlow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in using threads for this - that's just wasting resources.

Instead, you want to use asynchronous I/O. Now, ignoring all the complexities involved with networking, the basic idea is something like this:

```
async Task Loop()
{
    using(var client = new TcpClient())
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 6536).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] outBuf = new byte[4096];

        // The "message loop"
        while (true)
        {
            // Asynchronously wait for the message
            var read = await stream.ReadAsync(outBuf, 0, outBuf.Length);

            // Handle the message, asynchronously send replies, whatever...
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this method for each of the connection you're making (*without* using `await` - very important). The thread handling that particular socket will be released on every `await` - the continuation of that `await` will be posted on a thread-pool thread.

The result being, the amount of threads used at any given time will tend to self-balance with the available CPU cores etc., while you can easily service thousands of connections at a time.

**Do  not use the exact code I posted. You need to add tons of error-handling code etc.** Handling networking safely and reliably is very tricky.

Comment: Hmm..  I'm still old school C# so I never really learned about async and await.  I suppose I'll have to look into these.  Thanks!

Comment: @ZacharyTurner You can accomplish the same using the old asynchronous APIs (they're still there), but `await` is *much* more comfortable - it presents you with code that runs synchronously in its own context (if you avoid shared state, it's really as if it simply run synchronously - very easy to work with and reason about). Most importantly, the error handling is much easier, because you can just use the usual `try-catch-finally` blocks.